# OUTPUT AUC for SAS ROC curve from proc logistic

Tags: sas, logistic-regression, roc

I would like to save the AUC value for multiple ROC analysis and append them together so that I can quickly have a list of which combination of variables have the greatest AUC value.

I can't figure out how to output the AUC value but I can only the roc stats.

```
 ODS GRAPHICS ON;
    PROC LOGISTIC data = dataset PLOTS(only) = (roc(id = obs) effect);
       CLASS outcome ;
       MODEL outcome = var / scale = none 
                       clparm = wald
                       clodds = pl
                       rsquare OUTROC= RocStats;
    RUN;    
 ODS GRAPHICS OFF;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The AUC value is in variable `Area` in dataset `AUC` below:

```
PROC LOGISTIC DATA = SASHELP.CLASS;
    CLASS SEX;
    MODEL SEX = HEIGHT WEIGHT / OUTROC = ROC;
    ROC;
    ODS OUTPUT ROCASSOCIATION = AUC;
RUN;

TITLE "AUROC";

PROC PRINT DATA=AUC NOOBS LABEL;
    WHERE ROCMODEL = 'Model';
    VAR AREA;
RUN;
```

Comment: Thanks! I went looking in the proc logistic documentation for that I guess I should look in the  ODS output documentation.